# Leverage browser caching issue with already cached content

Tags: php, caching, browser-cache, amazon-cloudfront, google-pagespeed

Google Page Speed complains about following file (Leverage browser caching)

http://dy2em7yqysbvb.cloudfront.net/images/flags/az.png (expiration not specified)

In my browser file already come from cache with **304 Not Modified** HTTP STATUS CODE

[image]

I use Cloudfront cdn service of Amazon and my settings are shown below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration you specify here controls how CloudFront caches objects, not how they are cached by browser. You still need to send Cache-Control header from origin to control browser caching.